# unable to remove brackets around numbers with uncertainty siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am unable to remove the brackets around the number with its uncertainty. I did refer to the manual, but I guess I have not understood it correctly?

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{open-bracket=\, ,
        close-bracket=\, ,
        uncertainty-separator = \,} %manual page: 27
\sisetup{bracket-ambiguous-numbers = false} %manual page: 28
\begin{document}
The output I get: \qty{62.52(18)}{\micro\gram}.\par
What I want the numbers to look like:
62.52 \ensuremath{\pm} 0.18 µg.
\end{document}
```

Here is the corresponding output:
[image: Siunitx bracket problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```latex
\sisetup{
  separate-uncertainty-units=single,
}
```

though, as the documentation notes, this is mathematically incorrect.